# Socket & SDK minVersion

Tags: android

I coded an app before that uses the socket class to create a TCP/IP Client like this:

```
Socket soc;
DataOutputStream out;
DataInputStream in;

//in try-catch loop
soc = new ("192.168.1.101", 100);
out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

.....//code on I/O through socket
```

And it works fine on my previous ap, running sdk 9

Now I am trying to use the same function in my new app, which make uses of fragment and needed sdk 11. But the app crashes whenever it runs the socket code.
Once I change the android:minSdkVersion to 9 in manifest.xml, it works again. But I needed minSDK 11 for fragment.

What should I do? I have only code Android for few months, forgive me if I asked stupid question.Thanks a lot!

Edited: This is the OnClick function that triggered the Socket funcitons:

```
private Button.OnClickListener m_BtnConnectDisconnectOnClick = new Button.OnClickListener()
{
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
         try
         {
          //Obtaining IP Address & Port number
          String str_ip = m_EditPumpIP.getText().toString();
          int int_port = Integer.parseInt(m_EditPumpPort.getText().toString());

          //Establish Pump Connection
          socket = new Socket(str_ip, int_port);
          out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
          in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

          //Update Status
          m_TextSystemStatus.setText("OK");
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
           //Update Status
           m_TextSystemStatus.setText("Fail");
         }
   }
};
```

Comment: try to set in your manifest `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />`

Comment: post your logcat that could me you are running network on ui thread

Comment: @MoshErsan he needs minsdk 11

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn  yeah you are right.

Comment: @user2155836 just try to run your code in new thread.

Comment: @MoshErsan I tried adding targetSdkVersion="17" but it still crashes.

Comment: as @DjHacktorReborn said, maybe you are running socket connection on UI thread, show some code, or the logcat.

Comment: @MoshErsan, i added my code, please take a look. Thx!

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn, i added my code, please take a look. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Put this in AsyncTask

```
//Establish Pump Connection
          socket = new Socket(str_ip, int_port);
          out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
          in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
```

[Like This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example)